# ReactJS: How do I set a for loop to loop once every second?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, sorting, for-loop

I am trying to build a sorting algorithm visualizer that represents the values of an array as rectangles with different heights corresponding to each element's value. It's supposed to show each step of the algorithm's process, with every loop occurring after a second has passed. However, whenever the web page loads, the array is already sorted. I want to make it so that after every second, the position of the rectangle being sorted changes so that each step of the sorting algorithm is being shown. My code is below:

**index.tsx**

```
import SortingAlgorithm from '@/components/sorting-algorithm'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return(
    <div className='headerContainer'>
      <h1 className='header'>  </h1>
      <SortingAlgorithm />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**sorting-algorithm.tsx**

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const SortingAlgorithm: React.FC = () => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState<number[]>([3, 1, 2, 5, 4]);

  //Selection sort
  while (arr != arr.sort()) {
    useEffect(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const loop = setTimeout(() => {
        let minIndex: number = i;
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
          if (arr[j] < arr[minIndex]) {
            minIndex = j;
          }
        }
        let temp: number = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
        arr[minIndex] = temp;
        }, 1000);

        return() => clearTimeout(loop);
      }
    }, []);
  }
  
  return arr.map<JSX.Element>((keys) => (
    <div className='barsContainer'>
      <svg className='bars'>
        <rect height={keys * 25} width={100 - (arr.length * 10)} x={arr.indexOf(keys) * 53} y={0}/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  ))
}

export default SortingAlgorithm;
```

I've already implemented `setTimeout` inside the for loop containing the sorting algorithm. I thought it would be the perfect solution to my problem, yet it seems that it doesn't alter the speed at which the for loop loops. I've also tried playing around with the syntax, though that doesn't really seem to make a difference. A point in the right direction at least would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good question. Could you provide a minimal example so the problem can be reproduced? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As for what I want the timer code to do, I want it to it to make a for loop repeat once after every second. I'm hoping for it to end up something like this: https://hamdolavisualizer.netlify.app/

Comment: Here is a minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-http-wung2i?file=/src/App.js
Please let me know if I did not make it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what to do based off of another Stackoverflow post. I've decided to post my code below just in case someone else had the same issue and this is the first thing they find.

```
useEffect(() => {
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setArr(arr => {
      let arrCopy: number[] = [...arr];
      let minIndex: number = i;
      for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arrCopy[j] < arrCopy[minIndex]) {
          minIndex = j;
        }
      }
    let temp: number = arrCopy[i];
    arrCopy[i] = arrCopy[minIndex];
    arrCopy[minIndex] = temp;

    return arrCopy;
    })
  }, 100 * (i + 1));
}
```

}, []);

Comment: told you not to nest your `useEffect` and to use `setArr` ;)

Comment: Fair enough! You were right there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample implementation for a [full solution](https://react-ts-fyatj6.stackblitz.io).

Below, please see this minimal example with a counter that demonstrates in its most basic form what you are trying to accomplish:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function() {

  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() =>{
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setState(state + 1);
    }, 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, [state])

  return (
    <div>
      <span>Counter</span>
      {` `}
      {state}
    </div>
  );
});
```

A few notes on hooks:

1. [Never use a hook in a control flow structure](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) such
   as `if`, `while`, etc. A hook must be executed every single time
   your react function executes in order for them to work properly. If
   you check your dev console, you may see React warning or erroring
   about this.
2. React depends on `setState` to know when to update your component. Since you never call `setArr`, your component never updates. See [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Consider reading [the full documentation on hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) so you can develop a complete understanding of their intended uses.

Comment: Nesting my useEffect hook inside the while loop is the only way I'm able to get it to reliably sort my array, it also doesn't bring up any errors in my console. And whenever I attempt to put the changes to the array inside the parenthesis of setArr() it covers my code in syntax errors. I may try making a duplicate array that sorts the algorithm, then sets the original array to it at the end of the loop using setArr().

Comment: Frankly, you can't do that. It's not how hooks work.